# Force a link to open in a different browser (Intranet)

Tags: javascript, html, uri

We have an old .asp page application that runs only in IE. The problem is, most of the users are using Chrome or Firefox. Is there anyway possible to force a specific link to open in a different browser? I read that it is possible with URI SCHEME, but I wasn't able to find any good explanation.

As I mentioned, this is ONLY for intranet purposes. I know that it's impossible for users outside of the network.

Thanks

Comment: You're probably looking for something like PSExec installed on your server. Then you may be able to grab the computer ip address and pass your string needed to launch IE to PSExec. I would suggest biting the bullet and update your stuff. Someone's going to have to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Unfortunately I'm not in the position to update all the staff. That's why I need a workaround. I hope someone has a solution for my problem.

Comment: I'd say PSExec might be your goto